# StructureMap on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, structuremap

Is StructureMap supported on Windows Phone 7?
I was hoping to use StructureMap with CommonServiceLocator on WP7

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that StructureMap has binaries for WP7 or even SL4+.  That doesn't say you can't try and build them yourself.

Some that do work: Ninject, AutoFac, Funq, and Caliburn Micro has it's own SimpleContainer built in.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison, it should support WP7.